# Move document to specific library on command

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am wondering what is the best way to do this: In SP2013, I need to transfer documents from one library to another library (archives) on command (meaning, I can manually chose which documents I want to send to the archives library).This has to be done from within the library. Will this work with a workflow? Is there another/better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Site Settings-> Content and structure under Site Administration. You could move document there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I need this to be done within the library; for example, each item has a checkbox, that when is checked, the document is automatically transferred to the archives folder.